# Why JTDS connection error SSL on android version 10

Tags: android, sql-server, jtds

I am using jtds-1.3.1.jar to connect my android app to sql server DB. My app is working really fine on my pixel 5, Its android version is 12. But when I install the same app on android version 10 device it gives me the error

```
conclass: Network error IOException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7af1b3fb88: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
```

My connection string is something like this

```
 ConnectionURL= "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+ip+":"+port+";"+"databaseName="+ db+ ";user="+un+";password="+pass+";ssl=require";
```

Can someone please guide me.

Comment: Perhaps two better questions are: 1) why are you trying to use jTDS, a driver that hasn't seen a release since 2013? 2) why are you trying to directly connect from an Android device to Microsoft SQL Server? The TDS protocol is designed for use in a LAN environment and, being extremely "chatty", performs horribly over the open internet due to increased latency. A normal application would hide the database behind an ORM such as Hibernate, expose the entities through a web API of some kind, and have the clients use the much more efficient HTTP/S protocol to transfer data over the internet.

Comment: Aside... jTDS was an incomplete driver even back in 2013, amongst other things not having any support for nchar/nvarchar/ntext data types. Totally guessing here, but perhaps you're trying to connect to a modern SQL Server that only supports TLS 1.2 connections, or only supports a set of ciphersuites that aren't supported on your Android device.